# Trouble rendering results from searchbar in Django

Tags: html, django, view, searchbar

I have been working on a search bar in django and I am close but having some issues rendering the results to the page.

Views.py

```py
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'search_results.html'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        proj=self.request.GET.get('proj')
        proj_list=Project.objects.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=proj) | Q(projectTag__icontains=proj)
        )
        proj_list1=Project.objects.filter(
            Q(department__icontains=proj)
        )
        proj_list2 = list(set(proj_list) & set(proj_list1))
        return proj_list2

class SearchPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'searchbar.html'
```

search_results.html

```html
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
<html>

{%block content%}
<h1> Search Results </h1>

{% if proj %}
<ul>
    {% for project in proj_list2%}
     <li>
        {{project.name}}, {{project.department}}, {{project.projectTag}}
     </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<h2>sorry, no results</h2>
{% endif %}
{%endblock%}
</html>
```

Whenever I search something that should definitely yield results, I get "sorry, no results."

Thank you. Please help me to understand my disconnect. The bigger aim for this is to then add different models to query from (i.e. not just search in projects, but also search by user).

Comment: `{% if proj_list2 %}`

Comment: But the search is rather odd, you only return items that match *both* the department *and* the name or the tag?

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the wrong variable. The collection of elements is `object_list`, not `proj` or `proj_list2`:

```
{% if object_list %}
<ul>
    {% for project in object_list %}
     <li>
        {{project.name}}, {{project.department}}, {{project.projectTag}}
     </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <h2>sorry, no results</h2>
{% endif %}
```

The search is also quite odd, you only retrieve items if *both* the department *and* the name or the *tag* matches. We can simplify this to:

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'search_results.html'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        proj = self.request.GET.get('proj')
        return =Project.objects.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=proj) | Q(projectTag__icontains=proj),
            department__icontains=proj
        )
```

but it is *odd* that the department *and* the name for example should match. If you want to match any of the three, we can work with:

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'search_results.html'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        proj = self.request.GET.get('proj')
        return =Project.objects.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=proj) |
            Q(projectTag__icontains=proj) |
            Q(department__icontains=proj)
        )
```

Comment: Okay, but why is the collection of elements in object_list? If I want to save projects as one thing so that it queries through my Project table and renders a certain view of results, but I also want the search to be able to search by user and have that collection of elements query through my User table and render a different view of results.

Comment: @AndrewBregman: because a `ListView` passes the queryset to the template as `object_list`, and as `modelname_list` (with `modelname` the name of the model in lowercase).

Comment: @AndrewBregman: see the implementation of `get_context_data` of the `ListView`: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.1/django.views.generic.list/ListView/#get_context_data

Comment: @AndrewBregman: if you want to pass extra data, you override the `get_context_data`, and you can add extra items to the context, but the `ListView` will only take care of the queryset it obtains from the `get_queryset` method.

Comment: when I switched my code to """def get_queryset(self):
        proj=self.request.GET.get('proj')
        return=Project.objects.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=proj) | 
            Q(projectTag__icontains=proj) |
            Q(department__icontains=proj)
        )""" I got an error. I think this is why I structured the lists as I had in the original code, because I ran into an error when I tried to pass 3 arguments to filter for.

Comment: I figured it out, thank you so much for your help.